# Eclipse Maven unable to add dependencies (Google Drive)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I'm new to Eclipse and have been trying to do a Java Spring course on Udemy.

I've been pulling my hair out all evening trying to set up Maven on Eclipse. The problem was I couldn't add any dependencies. I googled all night and thought I had it solved by rebuilding the index, etc etc

However none of these worked. I then thought that maybe it had something to do with me having the Eclipse default workspace in Google Drive. I had another default workspace set up on my machine from before I moved everything to Drive so I changed to that and low and behold I was able to add dependencies to a project.

I then switched back to the Google Drive one and noticed that the problem related to a file called `_1j.cfs` which is stored in `..\Eclipse default workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core\nexus\26522e0d83a422eed93329ece7565cfc`.

I only noticed it because I was getting a message saying it could not be found when I clicked the `Enable Full Index` button under the Global repositories.

So then I decided to copy the file from my workspace outside of Google Drive to the one on Drive. I copied it twice and both times the file disappeared once I switched workspace back to the one on Drive.

Has anyone any idea what's going on? I'd much prefer to use the workspace on Drive because it means I can access it on my work computer too. I'm at a complete loss to why this file keeps disappearing. I've tried pausing the sync while switching etc. but nothing works.

Thanks for looking

Comment: You can try starting by the beginning. Download [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunar), create a new maven project, setup one dependency and check if it worked. So you can figure out if the problem is on your environment

Comment: I did consider that Fede but it would take too long to uninstall and re-install everything. Now that I have it working with the workspace on the local machine, I think I'll use Git to share those projects I'll be working on on more than one machine

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but you can have your source code on Drive and your workspace in some other place. Just create a new workspace outside of Drive folder and then do "Import" from filesystem or something like that. This way you'll end up with project in a workspace which physically resides in your Drive folder. Not sure if it'll help though.

If you're just looking to get stuff synced across multiple machines, I'd use a proper version control system. It brings more benefits then just synchronization and you'll probably need one at some point. I use Git and BitBucket to do just that. Make sure you push your changes to server when you finish something though.

Comment: Thanks dimoniy. I was thinking in my head that I could use Git to sync between machines. Just wondered had anyone seen anything like it before and if there was an explanation.